# Magento 404 is redirecting to home page instead of 404

Tags: magento, http-status-code-404

In Magento, I've got a problem with my 404 page not showing up.  For example, the following URL will redirect to the home page

http://www.site.com/page_does_not_exist

However, if I add the trailing slash the page will show the correct 404 page:

http://www.site.com/page_does_not_exist/

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Are you using the default .htaccess file? What happen if you try `http://www.site.com/index.php/page_does_not_exist` (if this work then check your rewriting rules in .htaccess)

Comment: +1 for htaccess, also if you're working locally or managing your own server, make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled and that `AllowOverride All` is set in your Apache config.

Comment: also check the rewritebase directive.